# Как вывести значения из объекта?

Tags: javascript

Как вывести значения из объекта в котором массив. Например `tooth.statusList.code`

```
tooth = {
  statusList: [
            {id: 1, code: "G", "decode": "Здоров"},
            {id: 2, code: "S", "decode": "Пломба"},
            {id: 3, code: "C", "decode": "Коронка"},
            {id: 4, code: "I", "decode": "Искусственный зуб"},
        ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Дополнение к ответу [@Igor](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/176262/igor)

```js
var tooth = {
  statusList: [
    {id: 1, code: "G", "decode": "Здоров"},
    {id: 2, code: "S", "decode": "Пломба"},
    {id: 3, code: "C", "decode": "Коронка"},
    {id: 4, code: "I", "decode": "Искусственный зуб"},
  ]
};

tooth.statusList.map(item => {
  console.log(`id: ${item.id}, code: ${item.code}, decode: ${item.decode}`);
});
```

Comment: а что дополнилось-то? И в данном случае лучше не map, а forEach

Answer (score 0):

```js
var tooth = {
  statusList: [
    {id: 1, code: "G", "decode": "Здоров"},
    {id: 2, code: "S", "decode": "Пломба"},
    {id: 3, code: "C", "decode": "Коронка"},
    {id: 4, code: "I", "decode": "Искусственный зуб"},
  ]
};
console.log(tooth.statusList[0].code); // G
```